Prediction with categorical data in semopy
I'm using semopy for the first time (I am more familiar with lavaan in R). I was able to apply the predict method for continuous, normally distributed data (for both one missing value and multiple missing values) using the example on the semopy website. However, I am struggling with using the predict method with categorical data.
I used an example dataset and tried to treat some variables (x1, x2, and x3) in the dataset as categorical.
Here is my code:
import semopy
import pandas as pd
dat = semopy.examples.political_democracy.get_data()
dat = dat.round() # make all scores integers

# Convert ordinal variables to categories
ordinal_vars = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']
for col in ordinal_vars:
    dat[col] = dat[col].astype('category')

# model syntax
mod = '''# measurement model
ind60 =~ x1 + x2 + x3
dem60 =~ y1 + y2 + y3 + y4
dem65 =~ y5 + y6 + y7 + y8
# regressions
dem60 ~ ind60
dem65 ~ ind60 + dem60
# residual correlations
y1 ~~ y5
y2 ~~ y4 + y6
y3 ~~ y7
y4 ~~ y8
y6 ~~ y8
# DEFINE(ordinal) y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7 y8 x1 x2 x3 # i only treat x1-3 as ordinal instead
DEFINE(ordinal) x1 x2 x3
'''

# generate missing value
i, v = 0, 'x1'
x = dat[v].values[i]

dat[v].values[i] = float('nan')

# fit model
fitmod = semopy.Model(mod)
fitmod.fit(dat, method = 'DWLS')

And here is the error I receive:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 42
     38 # print(dat)
     39 
     40 # fit model
     41 fitmod = semopy.Model(mod)
---> 42 fitmod.fit(dat, method = 'DWLS')
     43 preds = fitmod.predict(dat)
     44 print(preds)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/semopy/model.py:1097, in Model.fit(self, data, cov, obj, solver, groups, clean_slate, regularization, n_samples, **kwargs)
   1054 def fit(self, data=None, cov=None, obj='MLW', solver='SLSQP', groups=None,
   1055         clean_slate=False, regularization=None, n_samples=None, **kwargs):
   1056     """
   1057     Fit model to data.
   1058 
   (...)
   1095 
   1096     """
-> 1097     self.load(data=data, cov=cov, groups=groups,
   1098               clean_slate=clean_slate, n_samples=n_samples)
   1099     if obj == 'FIML':
   1100         if not hasattr(self, 'mx_data'):

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/semopy/model.py:1038, in Model.load(self, data, cov, groups, clean_slate, n_samples)
   1036     raise KeyError('Variables {} are missing from data.'.format(t))
   1037 if data is not None:
-> 1038     self.load_data(data, covariance=cov, groups=groups)
   1039 else:
   1040     self.load_cov(cov)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/semopy/model.py:901, in Model.load_data(self, data, covariance, groups)
    899 else:
    900     inds = [obs.index(v) for v in self.vars['ordinal']]
--> 901     self.load_cov(hetcor(self.mx_data, inds))
    902 self.n_samples, self.n_obs = self.mx_data.shape

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/semopy/polycorr.py:267, in hetcor(data, ords, nearest)
    265 c_z = {v: (data[v] - c_means[v]) / c_vars[v] for v in conts}
    266 c_pdfs = {v: norm.logpdf(data[v], c_means[v], c_vars[v]) for v in conts}
--> 267 o_ints = {v: estimate_intervals(data[v]) for v in ords}
    269 for c, o in product(conts, ords):
    270     cov[c][o] = polyserial_corr(data[c], data[o], x_mean=c_means[c],
    271                                 x_var=c_vars[c], x_z=c_z[c],
    272                                 x_pdfs=c_pdfs[c], y_ints=o_ints[o])

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/semopy/polycorr.py:267, in <dictcomp>(.0)
    265 c_z = {v: (data[v] - c_means[v]) / c_vars[v] for v in conts}
    266 c_pdfs = {v: norm.logpdf(data[v], c_means[v], c_vars[v]) for v in conts}
--> 267 o_ints = {v: estimate_intervals(data[v]) for v in ords}
    269 for c, o in product(conts, ords):
    270     cov[c][o] = polyserial_corr(data[c], data[o], x_mean=c_means[c],
    271                                 x_var=c_vars[c], x_z=c_z[c],
    272                                 x_pdfs=c_pdfs[c], y_ints=o_ints[o])

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/semopy/polycorr.py:95, in estimate_intervals(x, inf)
     93 sz = len(x_f)
     94 cumcounts = np.cumsum(counts[:-1])
---> 95 u = [np.where(u == sample)[0][0] + 1 for sample in x]
     96 return list(chain([-inf], (norm.ppf(n / sz) for n in cumcounts), [inf])), u

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/semopy/polycorr.py:95, in <listcomp>(.0)
     93 sz = len(x_f)
     94 cumcounts = np.cumsum(counts[:-1])
---> 95 u = [np.where(u == sample)[0][0] + 1 for sample in x]
     96 return list(chain([-inf], (norm.ppf(n / sz) for n in cumcounts), [inf])), u

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

I don't fully understand what the error means. I found this question, but was not able to fix the issue in my case. I am also relatively unfamiliar with Python, so perhaps there is a basic syntax error that I'm overlooking? Alternatively, perhaps it is not yet possible to predict with categorical data in semopy?

Hi, ambiguditi. This is not my field, but at a glance it seems more of a programming issue rather than an inherent statistical one, and that would make it off-topic . If it is otherwise, I would say make that explicit.

Hi, @User1865345, I think you're right. I will try to have the question migrated to stack overflow.

Flag the post for mod's attention and tell them to migrate it to SO. Or you can do it manually by deleting it and posting the same at SO :-)

Yes, already flagged the question :) I'll wait for a few hours otherwise delete and repost myself. Thanks for the help!

No problem. SO would be better place for your query.
